# Using WRAP_CONTENT, popupwindow gets hole screen width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-popupwindow

I am trying to create a `PopupWindow` with custom layout. Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/switch_iamge"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/switch_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/old_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch_iamge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here I am creating `PopupWindow`:

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 48);
```

However it gets hole screen width. I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503050/popup-using-popupwindow-or-dialog-fills-the-width-of-the-screen-for-no-apparen) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200724/listpopupwindow-not-obeying-wrap-content-width-spec), but they didn't help. What should I do?

**Edit:** It seems that the problem is in `ImageView`. Also using `wrap_content` in image don't work. So I removed `ImageView` and used `drawableRight` property in `TextView` and it works.

Comment: I think it will because your ImageView in your image is being displayed.

Comment: Try to fix TextView width and check.

Comment: @PiyushGupta So what is the problem? Images takes only 32*32 square space.

Comment: @HareshChhelana the problem is I don't want to use fix values for width.

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi found solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the popup window programmatically. You can't change it in the XML file. I faced the same problem. Put `match_parent` in your xml instead of `wrap_content`. Do something like this:

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view,120,220);
```

Hopefully, it helped :)

Comment: As I said, I don't want my popup to have fixed width.